# Vapor vs. Steam: What's more common for naming the thing that rises up from water bubbling in the kettle?

Tags: word-choice, word-in-context

What's more common for naming the substance that rises up from water bubbling in the kettle?

Here is some context:

> "I saw **vapor/steam** from the kettle, so I think it's already ready."
>
> "On a cold day, if you exhale you can see **vapor/steam** going out of
> your mouth."
>
> "The bread is still hot, look at the **vapor/steam** that rises from
> it"

Answer (score 2):

**steam** is used more  of food and beverages whereas **vapor** is  used more of chemical liquids and condensation.

> A steaming bowl of soup sounds like a perfect lunch on a cold day.
>
> A vaporous bowl of soup doesn't sound very appetizing.

Comment: Also, **steam** is particularly associated with **boiling** (or recently boiled) water or other liquids. [Your breath on a cold day](https://wonderopolis.org/wonder/why-do-you-see-your-breath-when-it-s-cold) doesn't come from anything boiling hot.

Comment: To an engineer or scientist, true steam (sometimes called 'dry steam' in the boiler industry) is invisible. What you can see is water vapour ('vapor' in US English), tiny droplets of water suspended in the air. If you have the type of kettle that does not switch off when it boils you can see the first couple of centimetres of what emerges from the spout are invisible, then the steam condenses to water vapour. But we say that soup 'steams'.

Comment: I understand OP's question to be asking about a *domestic* setting (tea kettle and fresh-baked bread) not a factory or a laboratory.

Comment: Yup, all but scientists think the white fluffy stuff is 'steam'. I wouldn't try to fight that for an ELL question.